# What is the asymptotically best algorithm for the euclidean Steiner tree problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, computer-science

**So I would like to know what the fastest (asymptotically, worst case runtime) exact algorithm for the Euclidean Steiner tree problem is.** (More precisely, I would like to know the best known algorithm and runtime bound pair.)

Searching the Web, I found:

- A [2010 "survey"](https://maths.durham.ac.uk/Ug/projects/highlights/CM3/Soothill_Steiner_report.pdf) on algorithms for the euclidean Steiner tree problem, which however seems a bit short for such an extensively researched topic and also does not seem to focus on asymptotic worst case runtimes.
- A more extensive and slightly newer [2013 survey](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10766-013-0243-z) that however seems to be mostly concerned with approximation algorithms with good constant approximation ratios.
- A quite recent [2020 Article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/net.22005?saml_referrer) on approaches for the Euclidean Steiner tree problem, which however focuses more on the currently considered approaches than on the best runtimes.

However, I didn't find any recent enough survey on the fastest (asymptotically, worst case) algorithms for the Euclidean Steiner tree problem, which is strange because the problem seems to be well studied, so I'm asking this question here.

By Euclidean Steiner tree problem, I mean the problem of finding a Steiner tree in the plane, with all points in the plane allowed as nonterminals.

Comment: It would help if you were specific about exactly what the problem is that you want to solve. Are we talking about finding the shortest network connecting finitely many given points in the plane?  Does the question include solving the problem on a flat torus or Klein bottle? In euclidean n-space? Infinitely many points, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this.

Comment: I found this: An ETH-Tight Exact Algorithm for Euclidean TSP https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/22M1469122

Comment: Thanks, this is quite interesting, however, TSP is the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: oops, my bad...